# Redirect Wordpress URL with htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to redirect a certain url (actually I have several hundred) to another URL with the following code, but it's not working.  The htaccess is in my wordpress root directory, where the wp-content files etc are. What am I doing wrong?

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

Redirect http://lifeandhealth.org/qr/049ow34gh9klhg3uqrf2   http://lifeandhealth.org/?p=58
```

Comment: Do you have `mod_alias` installed and enabled on your server?  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html

Answer (score 1):

1. Usually, you put your redirect lines **above** the WordPress
   htaccess calls (`#BEGIN WordPress`).
2. If that doesn't work, I'm uncertain if this will, but try to be as explicit
   as possible.

   `Redirect 301 /qr/049ow34gh9klhg3uqrf2
   http://lifeandhealth.org/?p=58`

   Change the 301 to 302 if the redirect is temporary.

This isn't exactly WordPress-specific functionality, so look [***this***](http://webmaster.iu.edu/tools-and-guides/maintenance/redirect-htaccess.phtml) is a good resource for more advanced redirects.

If that doesn't work, let me know in comments, and I'll try to updated with another (attempted) solution :)

**Some other things to keep in mind**

1. If that doesn't work, try redirecting the whole directory with a "/" at the end of the URLs (only do that if it's alright with you, remember it has different functionality)
2. Make sure there are no blank lines at top of .htaccess file
3. (more of a "PS:" thing) This is not a solution nor optimal for **large** number of redirects but [this WordPress plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/) is fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

Two tweaks:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^() index.php [L]
```

- Remove the RewriteBase
- Remove the `/` in front of `index`